# Breakpoint Debugging AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm using VS Code with AngularDart. I need to see, what values are inside some variables. Usually one can do that, by setting a breakpoint. But the debugger doesn't seem to work for web projects.

What's the best way to analyse the contents of my variables? How can I do that? Is this a feature that is supported in Webstorm?

I'm using 5.0.0 and Dartium doesn't seem to be supported anymore.

Comment: Have you tried using chrome debug tools? Breakpoints should work with the sourcemaps DDC provides.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted. That's exactly what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer I'm happy to mark it as valid answer. This is pretty amazing. Didn't think that this was possible. Great stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Dart Dev Compiler (DDC) you can use chrome devtools as you would debug any other scripts on the page. The DDC provides source maps so that you can debug the Dart code you would expect, even though DDC is really providing JS underneath.